# How could I rewrite this Flask with AJAX jQuery example using Vue.js instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, vue.js, axios

I want to reproduce this example using `Vue.js`, and a library like `axios` or `vue-resource`.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/jquery/#

Could anyone give me advice on where to start?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you know Vue.js, I'd suggest you build out the front-end first, then use Flask to serve data, much like a RESTful API. To do that, you could use Axios like to said (though I'd recommend the standard Fetch API) to make HTTP requests to you Flask server, and have your Flask server respond with JSON formatted data. Is there any specifics you'd like to know about?